# Rolls of wallpaper needed to decorate a room (Javascript puzzle)

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and am really struggling with this puzzle from CodeWars.

John wants to decorate a room with wallpaper. The room has dimension: width(w), height(h),length(l). One wallpaper roll has dimensions 52cm width, 10m length. He wants 15% more wallpaper than he needs to cover the room. In case of mistakes or miscalculations so he wants to buy a length 15% greater than the one he needs.

This is what I came up with:

```
function wallpaper(l, w, h) {
var totalArea= ((2*(l*h))+(2*(w*h))*1.15);  //wall area to be covered
var rollsNeeded= (Math.ceil(totalArea/5.2));
return rollsNeeded;
```

Some example text Cases:

```
Test.describe("wallpaper",function() {
Test.it("Basic tests",function() { 
  testing(wallpaper(6.3, 4.5, 3.29), 16);
  testing(wallpaper(7.8, 2.9, 3.29), 16);
  testing(wallpaper(6.3, 5.8, 3.13), 17);
  testing(wallpaper(6.1, 6.7, 2.81), 16);
})})enter code here
```

But my function always returns one less that the test case. So instead of 16 I get 15, instead of 17 I get 16. I don't know whether I've made a mistake with the math or the code...

Other notes:
All rolls (even with incomplete width) are put edge to edge
0 <= l, w, h (floating numbers), it can happens that w x h x l is zero
The integer r (number of rolls) will always be less or equal to 20

Comment: The first mistake I can see is that you are multiplying the width by 1.15 - you need to multiply the _length_.

Comment: @vlaz Not so: w * (h * 1.5) is the same as (w * h) * 1.5

Comment: Wait, I think I might be mistaken - that there is the length of _the room_, not the wallpaper. I do think the math is incorrect, though, I just can't figure out exactly what it needs to be.

Comment: @PeterSmith not that it makes much more sense even then, though - you're still not getting the total +15%

Comment: @vlaz Right! I hate maths that looks simple on a Friday afternoon. I think I need to draw it on a piece of (wall)paper!

Comment: @PeterSmith I know - Friday, right? It's also why I was confused at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way more of a maths problem than a code problem, so let's do the mathematics correct first:

Assuming that it's a cube shaped room, it has four walls and each is a rectangle with width and height. Moreover, opposing walls should be exactly equivalent.

So, John wants to put wallpaper over the entire area of all those four walls. It's presumably a weird room with no doors or windows on the walls but whatever. I assume he enters and leaves through the ceiling or floor.

A room has

- **width** of `w`
- **height** of `h`
- **length** of `l`

Which translate to:

- two walls using **width** and **height** as dimensions with an area of `w*h`
- the two other walls using **length** and **height** as dimensions which have an area of `l*h`

So here is the formula for the total area:

```
[2*(l*h)] + [2*(w*h)]
```

to get the extra material John needs, we add 15% to the *total*.

```
{[2*(l*h)] + [2*(w*h)]} + {[2*(l*h)] + [2*(w*h)]}*0.15
```

or

```
{[2*(l*h)] + [2*(w*h)]}*1.15
```

your code does the following calculation

```
{[2*(l*h)] + [2*(w*h)]*1.15}
```

which adds 15% to the area of only two walls. You want (and probably intended) to have the multiplication outside the outer brackets

```js
function wallpaper(l, w, h) {
  var totalArea= ((2*(l*h))+(2*(w*h)))*1.15;  //corrected
  var rollsNeeded= (Math.ceil(totalArea/5.2));
  return rollsNeeded;
}

function testing(result, expected) {
  console.log("Expected: " + expected + 
              "\ngot: "+ result +
              "\nsuccess: " + (result === expected));
}

testing(wallpaper(6.3, 4.5, 3.29), 16);
testing(wallpaper(7.8, 2.9, 3.29), 16);
testing(wallpaper(6.3, 5.8, 3.13), 17);
testing(wallpaper(6.1, 6.7, 2.81), 16);
```

As an addendum, you can simplify the total area formula

```
[2*(l*h)] + [2*(w*h)]
 = 2*l*h + 2*w*h
 = 2*h*(l + w)
```

which makes the code much shorter:

```javascript
var totalArea = (2*h*(l + w))*1.15;  //simplified
//or          : 2*h*(l + w)*1.15
//or even     : 2.3*h*(l + w)
```